# how do I override htaccess rule for a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have created following rule in the .htaccess file located at the root of my application as (like this, app_name/.htaccess )

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?client=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

The problem now is that I am not able to access the "captcha class" located in the 
classes folder **(http://app_name/classes/captcha.php?args=xyz&arg1=abc)** of the web application directory.
What is the best solution to this problem.
Please throw some light.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/classes/captcha.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?client=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't overwrite the rule, though—doesn't it not apply it if we're in the subdirectory..?

Comment: Ah, ok. So the above is the .htaccess you put in the subfolder? I though you meant you had to change the top one into that.